# Tomcat randomly returns 401 for POST request with binary file

Tags: java, http, ssl, tomcat

I am running a backbone.js app on frontend and Spring boot (2.13) app on Tomcat 9 as backend. We are using OpenJDK Java 11. (Corretto)
All my other requests(GET and POST) work. Only two POST requests that upload binary file sometimes return 401. We dont see anything in backend log for the unsucessful try, only Tomcat access log shows 401. The request fails immediately. Inspecting the requests in Chrome shows they looks the same - same number of headers and same values.

Sucessful request looks like this

[03/Dec/2019:13:49:49 +0100] 172.30.***.* - **user** CN=*****, O=****, C=** "POST /rest/taxUpload HTTP/1.1" 200 61 "https://*********.eu/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

Unsucessful request looks like this - there are always two lines in the access log

[03/Dec/2019:13:50:13 +0100] 172.30.***.* - **user** - "POST /rest/taxUpload HTTP/1.1" 401 1099 "https://*********.eu/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

[03/Dec/2019:17:13:40 +0100] 172.30.***.* - --- - "null null HTTP/1.1" 400 2297 "-" "-"

Requests were made for the same file, same browser, same user.
We use The DataSource Database Realm on Tomcat for authentication, we tried TLS1.1, TLS1.2,
Tomcat 8.5, different browser, all cache and timeout settings on SSL Connector in Tomcat.

Headers being sent

POST /rest/taxUpload HTTP/1.1

Host: *****.net

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 160093

Accept: */*

Origin: https://*****.net

X-CSRF-TOKEN: 344f5e99-b5e5-49c1-8711-27de638dd739

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundaryo5NZhRls0pjEqx8Z

Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Referer: https://******.net/

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1549123445.1568710333; CSRF-TOKEN=344f5e99-b5e5-49c1-8711-27de638dd739

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="443"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="250"
               scheme="https"
               xpoweredBy="false"
               server="****"
               disableUploadTimeout="true"
               maxSavePostSize="4096"
               clientAuth="false"
               keyAlias="default"
               keyPass="***"
               keystoreFile="***/default.jks"
               keystorePass="****"
               keystoreType="JKS"
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2+TLSv1.1+TLSv1"
               sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
               truststoreFile="***.jks"
               truststorePass="****"
               truststoreType="JKS"
               secure="true"
               relaxedQueryChars="[,]"
               acceptCount="250"
               acceptorThreadCount="2"
               compression="on"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
                    dataSourceName="jdbc/authority"
                    userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
                    userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" localDataSource="true"/>
```

Comment: can you add the headers that are being passed? also, can you detail the underlying infrastructure? where does that spring app has been deployed? there is an API Gateway in front of it? maybe even add the "faulty" code? usually, when you have "random" behaviors, it has something to do with time ( e.g: you are reaching a timeout and the connection is being cut )

Comment: I added the headers, we even tried running the browser on the same server as backend, issue still happened. As for timeout as I said, the failure happen immediately after sending the request.